# JQuery loop through div and build multi-line string based on data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two questions:

1.) As you can see I have multiple divs and I have `onclick` things going on when the `callout panel notes` `div` is clicked. It accesses the `data-category` attribute. I'm using

```
$(this).parent().parent().siblings().first().data("category");
```

To access it, which works, but it seems messy. I tried `parents().last().data(...)` but that never worked. I feel like there's a more efficient way. So any opinions would be appreciated.

2.) My next question I can't figure out. Some of the divs have the `selected` class (after I click on the div). Later I'm going to hit a button to grab the selected stuff, and send it through some ajax stuff. There are 5 other "categories" so I need the `.selected` content to be associated with the `data-category="a"`, ie, I need to make sure it only loops withing the that category. Can anyone help me loop through the `data-category="a"` and build a multi-line string with the `data-response-text` of the `.selected` classes?

The html is below:

```
<div class="row responses panel">
    <div class="small-12 column" data-category="a">
        <h3>Responses</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 column">
        <div class="callout panel notes" data-response-text="Info 1">
        Info 1
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 column">
        <div class="callout panel notes selected" data-response-text="Info 2">
        Info 2
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 column">
        <div class="callout panel notes selected" data-response-text="Info 3">
        Info 3
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 column">
        <div class="callout panel notes selected" data-response-text="Info 4">
        <div class="remove-response"></div>
        Info 4
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 column">
        <div class="add-new-box">
            <div class="add-new">
            Add Response
            </div>
            <div class="add-new-text">
                <input class="text-response" type="text" placeholder="Response">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<div><span class="button">Submit</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part you can do:

```
$(this).closest('.row.responses').children(':first').data('category');
```

If either `.row` or `.responses` are unique to that level elements, you can use that solely then.

For the second part, I assume "content to be associated with the data-category a" means elements insides `.row.responses` which firs element has `data-category="a"`. If so then you can do:

```
var str = "";
var sls = $('[data-category="a"]').parent().find('.selected');
sls.each(function() {
    str += $(this).data('response-text') + "\n";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First question: I would select the panel like so:

`$(this).find('[data-category]').data();`

I would then create a function that's called on each of the panels and then returns an array of the data you require from `.selected`

```
        function getData(panel) {
            var $selected = $(panel).find('.selected');
            var dataArr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $selected.length; i++) {
                dataArr.push($selected.eq(i).data().responseText);
            }
            return dataArr;
        }

        var panelData = getData($('the-panel-in-question'));
```